# Twilio SMS gateway - Blacklist / STOP back to database

Tags: sms, twilio

I apologize in advance if I am posting this question in the incorrect place.

Is it possible, when someone who received a message from my system via Twilio responds back with STOP, to get that information back to my database? I have looked over twilio docs and google and found next to nothing on this.

Just a point in the correct direction for docs regarding this would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [STOP recieving SMSes when using Twilio with C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548739/stop-recieving-smses-when-using-twilio-with-c-net)

Comment: No fruitful answers of how Twilio gets information to your application is there. I wish it was!

Comment: OK...update to my update.  We may not actually make the wqebhook request, but we do log hte message so you could pull your SMS logs and find messages with STOP as the body.  Edited the linked answer with this info

Comment: Hi, Jason! I'm Megan, with Twilio. I recently answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254499/twilio-check-if-phone-number-has-been-blacklisted/33356403?noredirect=1#comment54560397_33356403.